# Cloud Datastore API - php - GqlQuery - "SELECT * FROM kind_name WHERE __key__"

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gql, google-cloud-datastore

I have an application on GAE:php runtime and I'm using Google Cloud Datastore API to connect to the Datastore from my PHP app.

My question:

How can I query my database using keys, something similar to `"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id <= 1410611039"` in Sql.

My code:(I've seen people are using this query-string syntax and it works for them)

```
$gql_query = new Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQuery();
$gql_query->setQueryString("SELECT * FROM notification WHERE __key__ = KEY('notification', 1410611039)");
```

Some part of the error I get is
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception ... (400) Disallowed literal: KEY...`

My Datastore console view:
[image]

Everything is fine until I append `WHERE __key__ = KEY('notification', 1410611039)` to the query_string.

Comment: Cloud Datastore GQL is slightly different from App Engine GQL. I'm not sure of the exact issue here though: have you tried `notification` without the quotes?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried `notification` without the quotes, but still the same error. Unfortunately, there is no guide for Datastore API on how to make a Gql-string. I think `KEY('kind', 'name/id')` is a method for making a Datastore key, but it's not working via the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys are considered literals in Cloud Datastore GQL and require special handling.

If users will be providing values at runtime, we recommend using argument binding. This helps prevent malicious behavior such as injection attacks.

There are two ways to do this; both start with a key value:

```
$key_path_element = new Google_Service_Datastore_KeyPathElement();
$key_path_element->setKind('notification');
$key_path_element->setId(1410611039);

$key = new Google_Service_Datastore_Key();
$key.setPath([$key_path_element]);

$key_value = new Google_Service_Datastore_Value();
$key_value->setKeyValue($key);
```

`$key_value` can then be used either as a named argument:

```
$gql_query = new Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQuery();
$gql_query->setQueryString("SELECT * FROM notification WHERE __key__ = $theKey");

$name_arg = new Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQueryArg();
$name_arg->setName("theKey");
$name_arg->setValue($key_value);

$gql_query->setNameArgs([$name_arg]);
```

or as a positional argument:

```
$gql_query = new Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQuery();
$gql_query->setQueryString("SELECT * FROM notification WHERE __key__ = @1");

$number_arg = new Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQueryArg();
$number_arg->setValue($key_value);

$gql_query->setNumberArgs([$number_arg]);
```

If no user-provided input is being added to the query, another option is to explicitly allow literals in the request:

```
$gql_query = new Google_Service_Datastore_GqlQuery();
$gql_query->setQueryString("SELECT * FROM notification WHERE __key__ = KEY('notification', 1410611039)");
$gql_query->setAllowLiteral(true);
```

Here are some additional details on [argument binding](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/gql#argument_binding) and here is the [full GQL reference](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference).

Comment: Thank you for your clean explanation. So, I was missing `$gql_query->setAllowLiteral(true);`. My problem was that I didn't know "Keys are considered literals" and to be honest I still don't know what it means due to my english level! Would be great if someone could give me a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using the Java Datastore API. The solution in Java would look like this:

```
datastore = DatastoreOptions.builder()
.authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createApplicationDefaults())
.build()
.service();
String id = "asdf123";
Query<Entity> query = Query.gqlQueryBuilder(
    Query.ResultType.ENTITY, 
    "SELECT * FROM Task WHERE id = '"+id+"'")
    .allowLiteral(true)
    .build();
QueryResults<Entity> result = datastore.run(query);
while(result.hasNext()){
    Entity temp = result.next();
    //(...)
}
```